# collapsible set is not refreshing after deleting the element

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamically created collapsible set to which I am obtaining data from the table.

I want to delete the collapsible element after selecting the collapsible element and pressing delete button.

After pressing the delete button i am performing the delete query on localstorage. and I am successful in deleting from database.

after deleting, again i am querying the database to display the data in collapsible set.

But i am getting the data which was deleted previously.
i guess it's problem with refreshing the collapsible.

How can i avoid the data displaying in collapsible set.

```
$(document).on("expand", "div[data-role=collapsible]", function(){
         name = $(this).find(".ui-btn-text")
                       .contents()
                       .filter(function(){
                           return this.nodeType == 3;
                       }).text();

    });
```

Comment: how do you delete the selected item?

Comment: i will get the element name of which collapsible element is selected, then i will execute the query tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE wname="' + name + '"');

Comment: how do you retrieve the name? can you show the code?

Comment: i have edited and added in the question

Comment: if you force refresh (f5) the page after deleting, does the same happen?

Comment: i am running on the device. how can i do that???.. but if i reload the same page again after transition i will not get that data.

Comment: then you need to refresh `collapsible` this way `$('[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();` and `collapsible-set` this way `$('[data-role=collapsible-set]').collapsibleset('refresh');` after your delete. Also i forgot to ask you, do you delete the selected item using `.remove()` or you only delete data from database? One more thing, you can delete existing `collapsible` before appending new one dynamically by using `$('#collapsible-ID').remove()` before you execute the query again.

Comment: i was only deleting from database. how to use $('#collapsible-ID').remove(), since i am creating dynamically how can i get the id of collapsible??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30061/discussion-between-omar-and-user2143817)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, you should `.remove()` the *deleted (data)* `collapsible` markup from `DOM`, otherwise it will remain visible/accessible even after appending new data, unless you refresh the page and load fresh data.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gF7mm/)**